# Apparent bug in SO's javascript for the question box

Tags: support, javascript, firefox

I need to wait a lot in writing messages to SO because my keyboard's `Key Repeat Rate` gets very slow in Firefox.

I have the following settings in OS X

[image]

I have noticed that some process is continuously ON and then OFF, and so on.
If I type in SO's question box, the  process starts. It does not start when I write to the title -box.

The process seems to be related to SO's javascript.

**How can you find the process which slows me down?**

---

I use OS X Leopard, Firefox 3.5.

Comment: **Workaround for now** Type up you question somewhere else, then paste it into SO.

Comment: @jinguy: I would like to have a similar editor as in SO for offline writing such that I can see what is going on when I am writing. --- **Do you know how you can have such an editor?**

Answer (score 1):

I would try to duplicate this in Google Chrome, or Safari, first. Could be rogue extensions in Firefox.

Comment: I use only Adblock Plus, Firebug and Tree Style Tab. --- I have not seen the same problem in Safari nor Opera yet.